# EDB Postgres Replication Server - Database connection cannot be added. Controller database is not initialized yet

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, enterprisedb

I am using EDB Postgres Replication server to setup a replication for my EDB Advanced Server.
Running it on 3 VMs using Centos 7. All have Advanced Server 13 installed.

Creating a Single-Master Replication (SMR)
Publication Server has been setup and a database has been appointed as the **controller database**.

Encountering a problem when creating the Subscription server, receiving an error of **Database connection cannot be added. Controller database is not initialized yet.**

All server services are running and all have the proper connection on the configuration file.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you try adding Publication server first?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.